# Direction style issue with react native android

Tags: android, react-native, styles

I'm working on a right-to-left react native app and want to handle layout with `direction: 'rtl'` or `direction: 'rtl'`.

It works fine with ios but it doesn't work on Android for no reason.

An example code is :

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', direction: 'rtl'}}>
  <Text>
    right content
   </Text>
   <Text>
    left content
   </Text>
</View>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direction props is only for iOs.
Refer documentation 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#direction

If you want to layout your views from right to left then below code would work.

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between',flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}>
    <Text> text1  </Text>
    <Text> text2  </Text>
    <Text> text3  </Text>
    <Text> text4  </Text>
    <Text> text5  </Text>
  </View>
```

Comment: Thanks .. but what's an alternative solution for android ?

Comment: Apparently we can use flexDirection: 'row-reverse' instead
Please update your answer to include the alternative solution as well

Comment: Sorry, i did not add complete code in my previous answer. I added new one with code as well.

Comment: You can just use `flexDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? "row-reverse" : "row"`

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17361 also try the "prefixing all the text  RTL with \u200F"